# How to count the occurrence of all characters in String?

Tags: java, string

```
package opop;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Domashnoto {

    static public void main(String[] args){

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Text:");
        String s = input.next();

        s = s.toLowerCase();
        s = s.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]+", "");
        s.replaceAll("\\s+", "");


        int j;
        int i;

        for (j = 0 ; j <= s.length() ; j++){
            int counter = 0;
             for (i = 0 ; i <= s.length(); i++){
                if(s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(j)){

                    counter++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(s.charAt(i) + " " + "-" + " " + counter);
        }



    }

}
```

HELP! I just don't know what is not ok

Comment: Use a map where the character is the key and the amount of occurrences is the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest approach (only works because there can only be 65536 different characters:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "asdfasdfasasasasa";
    int[] counters = new int[65536];

    for (char c: s.toCharArray()) ++counters[c];
    for (int i = 0; i < counters.length; ++i) {
      if (counters[i] > 0) System.out.println((char)i + " - " + counters[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: It is not necessary to initialize the array with zeros as Java does that already.

Answer (score 1):

Your two `<= s.length()` tests on the loops should be `< s.length()`.

`System.out.println(s.charAt(i)...` should be `System.out.println(s.charAt(j)...`, as the `i` loop has finished at that point.

This statement: `s.replaceAll("\\s+", "");` does not do anything as you do not assign the result back to `s`. It would remove spaces from the string, but it does not matter anyway as the line above already removes all non alphabetic characters.

If you fix those first couple of things it will work.

---

However, for a completely alternative approach that is a little cleaner and avoids reporting the same characters repeatedly, you can use a [map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html) that maps characters to integer counts of their frequency, like this:

```
Map<Character,Integer> charMap = new HashMap<>();
for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
    if (!charMap.containsKey(c)) {
        charMap.put(c, 1);
    } else {
        charMap.put(c, charMap.get(c) + 1);
    }
}
```

It iterates each character (`c`) of the string and if the map does not contain that character already, assigns a frequency of `1`, or if it does contain it, it gets the previous frequency, adds 1, and puts it back.

Then you can iterate the map to display the frequencies:

```
for (char c : charMap.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(c + " - " + charMap.get(c));
}
```

The order of the characters from that [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) will be essentially random. You can change it to [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) to preserve the order of first appearance of each character, or [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) to sort it alphabetically.

(P.S. To use this approach, you will also need to `import java.util.*;` or import the specific classes.)